# Adding Vertical space using Autolayout programmatically

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am trying to add a Custom View to an existing UIScrollView programmatically. I surfed the net and found possible solutions but the solution mess up the existing Autolayout. I need to add a vertical space between the super view of the custom view(i.e.- scroll view) and the custom view. So that whenever a user switches from a larger screen(iPhone5) to smaller(say iPhone4s) or vice versa the custom view is adjusted accordingly on the screen.

```
-(void) createEventsOnScroll
{
    [imageScroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.imageArray.count*imageScroller.frame.size.width, imageScroller.frame.size.height)];
    [imageScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(imageScroller.frame.size.width*self.selectedEventIndex,0)];
    imageScroller.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

    for (int i = 0; i<self.imageArray.count; i++)
    {
        EventCustomView *event = [[EventCustomView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*320+5, 3, 310, 435)];
        ChildImage *child = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:child.imageURL];
        event.eventImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        [event.eventImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        event.noteView.delegate = self;

        [imageScroller addSubview:event];

        event.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        imageScroller.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        NSMutableArray *constraints = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        [constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[event]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(event)]];

        [constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[event]-5-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(event)]];
    }

    imageScroller.bounces = NO;
    imageScroller.delegate = self;
    [imageScroller setClipsToBounds:NO];
    imageScroller.scrollEnabled = YES;

    imageScroller.pagingEnabled = YES;   
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is messing up? You need to actually ask a question. At the moment this is just code.

Comment: IMHO, Autolayout + UIScrollView = mess-up! Even documents from Apple admits that it is tricky. See the iOS 6.0 Release notes

Comment: @Fogmeister The Autolayout which I apply to the xib messes up. I mean I have added vertical space to the xib so that whenever a user switches from 3.5" screen to 4" screen or vice-versa the view is adjusted accordingly. But what now happens is the Custom view which I am adding to the UIScrollView Runs away from the superview(goes far way down the screen) rather than remaining in place.